# Update label in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

//    NSLog(@"msgcnt123 %@\n",[messageCount objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    NSArray *seperateArray = [[clist objectForKey:[[clist allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
//    NSLog(@"key %@\n",[[clist allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [seperateArray objectAtIndex:0];
//    cell.textLabel.text = [contactlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

//    NSLog(@"sep %@\n",seperateArray);


    if (![[seperateArray objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        NSLog(@"msgCount %@\n",[seperateArray objectAtIndex:1]);
        lblCnt = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 13, 20, 20)];
        lblCnt.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        lblCnt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblCnt.text = [seperateArray objectAtIndex:1];
        lblCnt.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblCnt.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        lblCnt.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblCnt];
        lblCnt.tag = 1000;

    }
    else
    {
        /*NSLog(@"msgCount1 %@\n",[seperateArray objectAtIndex:1]);
        [lblCnt removeFromSuperview];
        lblCnt.hidden = YES;*/
        for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
        {
            if (view.tag == 1000) 
            {
              [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }

    }

    return cell;
}
```

I am displaying contact name with a label in UITableView.The label displaying number of received messages for each contact.My view name is chatViewcontroller.If I am in that view that label count does not updated.For ex:For contact name "John" label count is "2".When John receives a message that label count should be updated as "3".It is not happening so.It is updated if i move come from another view.Is it possible to Update tableView chatviewController itself?.

Comment: just reload the table while updating

Comment: u mean [tableview reloadData].it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you updated your datasource(`clist`) and then call  `[tableview reloadData]`

Comment: when we call reloadData viewWillAppear call again or not?